# Eclipse Juno CDT running in Linux - it does not give me any toolchain

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using Slackware 14 and latest Eclipse Juno.

As a regular Eclipse user, I installed CDT just like I always did. However, when I create a new project, there is no toolchain available. Screenshot here:

[image: No toolchain available to choose]

I remember I used to get the default GCC toolchain available as soon as I have CDT installed in Linux. Even if using BSD, I could install GCC cross compile toolchain and it just works for native GCC as well. I tried to install the cross compile toolchain and CDT does not pick it up.

Please offer your suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. At some point, I could program in C++ with Eclipse. One day, it can't find any tool chain even when there are a couple of them. Basically, you need to reinstall your CDT plugin with assumption that you installed your tool chain in a correct place - for this, you need to refer to instructions for your Linux distribution.

Here is what I did without changing anything on toolchain:

1. Uninstall CDT from Eclipse

   Help -> Install new software -> Click the link "Already installed" -> Select CDT items -> Click Uninstall
2. [Install CDT again](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php)

This got me my toolchain back in Eclipse.

In case reinstalling does not work, it means you have unsupported toolchain for some reason. Uncheck `Show project types and toolchains only if they are supported on the platform` on the new project dialog. Then it will show the toolchain. You can go ahead to select the toolchain to create the project. But I'd try to find why the installed gcc is unsupoprted.

Comment: I already tried to reinstall CDT but it doesn't help. Do you know how CDT detects available toolchain?

Comment: @HowardGuo In that case, find what happens if you uncheck `Show project types and toolchains only if they are supported on the platform` on the new project dialog.

Answer (score 1):

you should install it from help menu

Comment: Please suggest the name of my missing plugin